# "Unfortunately your app has stopped" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a network based android project. Over the last 3 days I've been getting some error in my project. Please give me a solution for my problem to complete my project. In my project, whenever I'm including a Socket java program, I'm getting "Unfortunately your app has stopped"....
In my project I'm calling the `send()` function by using `UDP_Client.send()` from another java class. In my logcat I'm getting some error. Here I have attached the error logs.

```
        public class UDP_Client {
    public void Send() throws IOException
    {
      Socket s = null;
      DataOutputStream os = null;
      DataInputStream is = null;
      try
      {
          s = new Socket("192.168.0.102", 3000);
          os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
          is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
      }
      catch(UnknownHostException e){
          System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
      }catch(IOException e){
          System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
      }
      if(s!=null){
         try {
             os.writeBytes("HELLO\n");
         } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
        else {
          mStatusView.setText(formatStatusMessage(R.string.btstatus_connecting_to_fmt, "not connected"));
      }

        os.close();
        is.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
07-23 17:34:25.952966-3505/? W/ReauthClient? Network error calling reauth settings.
07-23 17:34:25.9552930-7535/? D/IPCThreadState? [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x60b69298
07-23 17:34:25.96128495-28505/? D/IPCThreadState? [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x5d267fc0
07-23 17:34:25.966  28495-29145/? E/KeepSync? IOException
    com.google.android.apiary.AuthenticationException: Could not get an auth token
            at com.google.android.apiary.GoogleRequestInitializer.getAuthToken(SourceFile:150)
            at com.google.android.apiary.GoogleRequestInitializer.intercept(SourceFile:89)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.b$a.intercept(SourceFile:220)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(SourceFile:858)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(SourceFile:410)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(SourceFile:343)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(SourceFile:460)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.b.a(SourceFile:194)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.KeepSyncAdapter.a(SourceFile:217)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.KeepSyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SourceFile:147)
            at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:254)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: NetworkError
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.apiary.GoogleRequestInitializer.getAuthToken(SourceFile:140)
            at com.google.android.apiary.GoogleRequestInitializer.intercept(SourceFile:89)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.b$a.intercept(SourceFile:220)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(SourceFile:858)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(SourceFile:410)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(SourceFile:343)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(SourceFile:460)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.b.a(SourceFile:194)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.KeepSyncAdapter.a(SourceFile:217)
            at com.google.android.keep.syncadapter.KeepSyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SourceFile:147)
            at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:254)
07-23 17:34:25.96628495-29145/? W/KeepSync? Sync result 2
07-23 17:34:25.967529-576/? D/ConnectivityService? getActiveNetworkInfo:null
```